# Google Music's cover art, song name, pause and play don't appear in my notifications

Tags: notifications, google-play-music

I have a Razr Maxx HD on Verizon and noticed that unlike my friends' Androids, when I play music using Google Music, the album art, song name, and pause/play notification isn't present.

In fact, if I start a track using Google Music and then go Home, the music keeps playing, but there's not "headphone" icon in the collapsed notification area, and so the only way to get back to that track is to go to Google Music or click on the cover art in the widget.

Any idea how I can get Google Music to show up in my notifications when a track is playing?

Comment: are you using the latest google music?...its possible that might be a bug and it would have been corrected in the latest update

Answer (score 2):

After WEEKS of having this problem, I figured this out.  In System -> Apps, under the Google Play Music app, I had "Show Notifications" set to not display.  Doh!